# Is "ultimated" a word?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is "ultimated" a valid word?

For example:

> Range requests were originally proposed by Ari Luotonen and John Franks, using an extension to the URL syntax instead of a separate header field. However, this approach proved less general than the approach **ultimated** used in HTTP/1.1, especially with respect to conditional requests. [(source)](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html)

Comment: Typo: "than the approach **ultimately** used in HTTP/1.1"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a typo.

Comment: @Kris, It's not based on a typo. It's based on "ultimated sounding like a valid word". If it's *simply* a typo, this question wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: It shouldn't have is what is meant. No offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Ultimated' is not a 'word' for two reasons

- it is not a common standard or an accepted variant to make a verb out of an adjective directly. It would be very colloquial (or even a sign of very gross invention) to do so. If it were done nowadays it would most likely mean 'to make ultimate'.
- in this context, a past participle is not expected but rather an adverb. This is probably a typo and what is most likely intended is 'ultimately'

> ...this approach proved less general than the approach **ultimately** used in HTTP__

Comment: It's definitely a typo for "ultimately", but I don't think it's true that making verbs from adjectives is unheard of. People use "obsolete" to mean "render obsolete", for example.

Comment: I agree, but, incidentally, in my country I notice a large usage of this word in pubblicty. However, I know, this does not mean anything.

Comment: By using this word, they publicize not only their computer expertise, but also the fact that they do not speak English correctly.

Comment: @GEdgar - Yes, you are right. It must be just so, because here only few people speak English as second language. It is preferred French.

Comment: @GEdgar: or to put it another way, the English they use is not the same as the English you use.

Answer (score 4):

I found *ultimate* listed as a verb in [this online dictionary](http://dictionary.die.net/ultimating).  Having found evidence that it *is* a legitimate (if not somewhat dated and out-of-vogue) verb, I checked the ultimate dictionary source, the OED.

The OED lists *ultimate* as a verb, meaning, *"To carry to an end; to complete,"* with these three excerpts cited as example uses:

> 1849   E. H. Sears Regeneration (1859) iii. i. 131   *Works are filled and vitalized by that angelic benevolence which is not complete until clothed and ultimated in action*.
> 1866   B. R. Parkes Vignettes 399   *My parents had seen my education ultimated in practical life*.
> 1881   E. S. Holden Sir W. Herschel 53   *His researches on the construction of the heavens would have been made; those were in his brain, and must have been ultimated*.

By the way, just because it *is* a word doesn't negate what Mitch said above. As a matter of fact:

> *the approach ultimately used*

does indeed appear more correct than

> *the approach ultimated used*

so I agree that, in this case, it's probably an error in the text.  Still, though, to ultimate the discussion, it's worth noting that *ultimated* can be used as a word.

Comment: Nobody disputes that it is possible to backform a verb from an adverb. The problem is that this hasn't yet been done with *ultimate*; in your third example, the coiner seems to intend *terminate prematurely*, which is entirely logical, but the opposite of *carry to an end*. If it were possible to create a word merely by typing it, millions of schoolchildren should have been rewarded for a new word, not marked down for misspelling.

Comment: +1 for "it's worth noting that ultimated can be used as a word". In my country "ultimated" is largerly used in pubblicity, where it assume a positive connotation: the people want to pay only for "ultimated things".

Comment: @Tim: those aren't my examples; I just copied-and-pasted them from the dictionary, and the originals were penned over a century ago.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: OED actually has **two** entries for *ultimate* as a verb. The first has two definitions - *To carry to an end; to complete.*, and *To result finally; to end (in something).* The second (listed as "rare") is the one defined as a *Back-formation from ultimatum n.* Whichever definition you go with, it's unreasonable to refer to OP's cited writer as a "coiner" - *the word **does** exist, and has been used by others*.

Comment: Thank you, FF.  While we're at it, OED also has more citations than the three I provided.  (I was only trying to give a sampling to make a point; I didn't feel like both entries and all examples were necessary, but maybe I should have been less abridged and more thorough.)